# Semi-colon missing after json_decode()?

Tags: php, regex, json

In PHP, I am loading a config file written in JSON. See extract:

```
"test":{
    "regexp":"^var1=([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(;var2=([0-9]+))?(;var3=([0-9]+))?$"
}
```

Notice the semi-colons!

When I load this in PHP 5.3.3 using json_decode() the following is returned as a string:

```
^var1=([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(var2=([0-9]+))?(var3=([0-9]+))?$
```

Anybody know what's happened to my semi-colons? They're kinda important!

Comment: What does happen if you encode (json_encode) for example: array('test'=>'test;test'); ?

Comment: Seems to work fine when encapsulated in `{}`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZBe0mz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP 5.3.21 it works pretty well
Here's my code

```
<?php 
    $json = '{"test":{"regexp":"^var1=([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(;var2=([0-9]+))?(;var3=([0-9]+))?$"}}';
    $tested=json_decode($json, true);
    echo $tested["test"]["regexp"];
?>
```

And my output is as expected

```
^var1=([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(;var2=([0-9]+))?(;var3=([0-9]+))?$
```

Comment: Thanks for ruling out a bug in the `json_*` functions. After looking back through my code, I need to rather sheepishly concede that I found  a rouge `str_replace(';',null,$json)` which was removing them.